# Disabling Krumo in Drupal Services

Tags: drupal, drupal-services, krumo

When I inspect a method in drupal services, I get the output formatted with something called Krumo. It wasn't like this before, it was just an array dump. I'm not sure what happened to cause this Krumo to get activated. Is there a way I can turn it off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try disabling the devel module. 
If you do ever want to use krumo devel and it's kpm() function is really useful.